# How to fill in credentials in Facebook popup with Webdriver (javascript)

Tags: javascript, facebook, selenium-webdriver

I have this site in which there is you can authenticate using Facebook. Unfortunately my site is not public at the moment, but to give you an idea you can see it in action at [agar.io](http://agar.io) -> click `Login and play` and click `Sign in with Facebook`. Now you get a popup window.

With Webdriver I can easily control the page, but I don't know how to access this popup window (using javascript) ?

My code is like this:

```
var browser = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities({
'browserName': 'chrome'
```

}).build();

From there on I can navigate my site. But how do I get from the `browser` object to this popup window such that I can fill in the credentials?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do anything special to handle the popup. This pseudocode should describe the solution (all selectors work):

```
click by XPath: //button[text()='Login and play']
click by XPath: //button[span/text()='Sign in with Facebook']
wait until CSS path exists: #facebook body
<any additional form-filling>
click by XPath: //button[text()='Play Now']
```

Comment: After I have the facebook dialog I get the following error: `NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#loginform"}` This should select the parent element around the input fields of the facebook-dialog. My code: `browser.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#loginform')).then(function (element) { ... });` Is there something wrong in my approach ?

Comment: Sounds like good progress. I can't see `#loginform` myself - I don't get the input fields, just the Play Now button - but perhaps try an Inspect on the popup to find it. I'll have a try later.

Comment: OK, I had to log out of FB to see the fields. I guess your test may need to use the FB API behind the scenes so you can test both combinations. I'm seeing the <form> as #login_form, not #loginform if that helps.

Comment: I don't think you can login without the popup using only the API. Anyway, I figured it out. You should `switchTo` the popup handle using `browser.getAllWindowHandles`. Then you can simply fill in the input fields and login - I have it working!